# Why does my dome light and "door ajar" light come on when I make a right turn?

Tags: electrical, honda, civic, door

When making right hand turns, my open door light flashes, the dome light flashes and I hear the locks clicking. Only happens on right turns.

40,000 miles on a 2014 Civic

Answer (score 3):

There should be a little push button sensor on the inside of the door jam, towards the back of the car, on the front and rear driver (left) side doors. Should be held in by maybe one bolt. Unbolt the push button sensor, and spray it with contact cleaner, and bolt it back in.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a short in the wiring loom - as you turn right then the damaged wire makes contact causing the light to come on etc. However, good luck finding it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the doors on the left side doors are properly closed? Door locks often have 2 'stages'; when the door is shut with too little force only the first stage engages. The door won't open on its own, but it'll have enough wiggle room to trigger the door sensors.

Answer (score 0):

In some vehicles the switch is adjustable (e.g. vans where all the clearances are bigger).  In others it's possible for the door hinge to be a little loose.  Then the changing forces going round a corner cause the switch to release a little too willingly.